# Make a deep copy of a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, copy

I have a Dictionary called baseDictionary. The key is a string and the values are the properties of a class called myData. In partiular the properties are: "age" (as int), "nationality" (as string) and "income" (as double).

So baseDictionary has some string as key and for each key a series of properties related to a specific person. 
I want at some point to make a deep copy of this dictionary so that I can then work with this new copy without modifying the content of the original dictionary. 
I have found an answer in stackoverflow where the following code is suggested to do this deep copy:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
     CloneDictionaryCloningValues<TKey, TValue>(
         Dictionary<TKey, TValue> original) where TValue : ICloneable
{
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ret = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(
         original.Count, original.Comparer);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry in original)
    {
        ret.Add(entry.Key, (TValue) entry.Value.Clone());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot understand how I should modify it to make it work with my dictionary. For example I tried:

```
public static Dictionary<string, myData> CloneDictionaryCloningValues<TKey, TValue>
                    (Dictionary<string, myData> original) where TValue : ICloneable
    {
        Dictionary<string, myData> ret = new Dictionary<string, myData>(original.Count,
                                                                original.Comparer);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, myData> entry in original)
        {
            ret.Add(entry.Key, (myData)entry.Value.Clone());
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

But I get the following error and it doesn't work.

> *Error    3   'Project2.myData does not contain a definition for 'Clone' and no extension method 'Clone' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Project2.myDatacould be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)*

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to change the `CloneDictionaryCloningValues` method at all, if you make the `myData` class implement the `ICloneable` interface:

```
public class myData : ICloneable {

  // your code

  public object Clone() {
    // whatever you need to create a copy, for example:
    return new myData() {
      age = this.age,
      nationality = this.nationality,
      income = this.income
    };
  }

}
```

You can also rewrite/overload the method to take a cloning method instead of demanding the `IClonable` interface:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> CloneDictionaryCloningValues<TKey, TValue>
   (Dictionary<TKey, TValue> original, Func<TValue, TValue> clone)
{
  Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ret = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(original.Count, original.Comparer);
  foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry in original) {
    ret.Add(entry.Key, clone(Value));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Then you call the method with a function that creates a copy of an item:

```
myCopy = CloneDictionaryCloningValues(myOriginal, item => {
  // whatever you need to create a copy, for example:
  return new myData() {
    age = item.age,
    nationality = item.nationality,
    income = item.income
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to modify the class to implement iCloneable. I just had to modify IClonable with ICloneable (just a typo) and few other things to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the `CloneDictionaryCloningValues()` routine, just use it as it is. Because its generic, it will work with your keys (strings) and value class (mydata).

**BUT:**

To make this routine work your class must have a public `Clone()` routine i.e. implement the `ICloneable` interface.

Comment: Do you mean in myData.cs?

Comment: @mickG lookup on ICloneable on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

As the function specifies: you need to implement ICloneable on the type `myData`

Also:

- Keep the original code and simply pass your dictionary.
- Rename the `myData` class to something more descriptive and have it start with an uppercase character